# Delete row on sheet if value matches textbox value from form?

Tags: search, excel, delete-row, userform, vba

Ok, So I have a userform in excel, and I have a textbox called "IMEITextBox" on the form. I have a inventory sheet that have IMEI numbers in Coloum B that I have in stock. When I enter an IMEI number in the IMEITextBox, I want it to delete the row containing that IMEI numbe from sheet "Inventory" when I save. I have researched this over and over for days now. Cant seem to find anything that works for me. Can you assist?

```
Sub DeleteRows(IMEI)

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
Dim strSearch As String
Dim aCell As Range

On Error GoTo Err
Set ws = Sheets("Inventory")
lastRow = ws.Range("IMEIRange" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
strSearch = IMEITextBox.Value
Set aCell = ws.Range("IMEIRange" & lastRow).Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
  ws.Rows(lastRow).Delete
End If
Exit Sub
Err:
MsgBox Err.Description

End Sub
```

Comment: Use `.Find` to find the IMEI numbers in Coloum B and once it is found, simple delete it. See Section 1 in this link http://siddharthrout.wordpress.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/

Comment: I know you need to use a .find. I do not program in VB, so can you provide code for this?

Comment: Please check the above link. It has code + entire tutorial on .Find :)

Comment: I have seen the link and the examples before you even posted it. I need the code as that link doesn't not fit my needs.

Comment: Jason Trust me... that link does fit your needs. Use the code to identify the row which has the IMEI number. Give it a try and then post the code that you tried and we will take it from there :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout Ok, I added my code..I am not skilled in VB at all. Getting a range error. I did make a range with a defined name of "IMEIRange" =Inventory!$B$2:$B$496 Any ideas?

Comment: For a person who doesn't know VB... I must say you have done pretty well :) I will amend your above code and post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have commented the code so that you will not have a problem understanding it... After seeing the code, you will realize that you were very close ;)

```
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteRows()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim strSearch As String
    Dim aCell As Range

    On Error GoTo Err

    '~~> Set the sheet where you want to search the IMEI
    Set ws = Sheets("Inventory")

    With ws
        '~~> Get the value which you want to search
        strSearch = IMEITextBox.Value

        '~~> Column A is Column 1 so Column B is 2. This is where we are searching
        '~~> xlWhole is used in the code below so that we find a complete match
        '~~> xlPart is supposed to be used when you are finding a partial match.
        Set aCell = .Columns(2).Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        '~~> Check if we found the value
        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            '~~> get the row of the cell where we found the match and delete it
            .Rows(aCell.Row).Delete
        Else '<~~ If not found
            MsgBox "IMEI Number not Found"
        End If
    End With

    Exit Sub
Err:
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

Comment: @Jason: If you want to specifically search in the `IMEIRange` range then change `.Columns(2).` to `.Range("IMEIRange").`

Comment: Ok, so I pasted everything in and used the .Range("IMEIRange"). I cant put in "Option Explicit" in my code, as it moves it above the line and effects my other code. I don't get any errors, and it still doesn't delete the row with IMIE "12345" as a test.

Comment: 'Option Explicit` has to be right at the very top in your code window. When you run the above code do you see a message box "IMEI Number not Found"?

Comment: No I don't get the error either. If I add 'Option Explicit` at the top of window, It start giving me errors on my subs.

Comment: remove `Option Explicit` for the time being. We will come to that later. Now try the code.

Comment: Still not working, is there a place I can upload my workbook for you?

Comment: You may upload the file in www.wikisend.com and share the link here :)

Comment: Wait I got it...lol. I had put the Clear sub before the delete row sub, so it was clearing the fields before it grabbed the info to search to delete the row. geez lol thanks for your help!

Comment: I will be posting another question if I can't find an answer. Trying to also see if a row is deleted to email and specified email address using outlook.